# new virtual server, php and apache

Tags: server, apache2, php

I've just rented a virtual server ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 and php running. I know a lot of the *nix world but this is my first virtual server so I'm a bit newbie with it and with all the web/http/domains world.

So, I have an ip, say *1.2.3.4*. I have ssh root access to it, I've created an `info.php` file in `/var/www/html directory` (*apache* `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`) but if I connect with the browser to http://1.2.3.4/info.php it says ***Not Found***.

If I connect to http://1.2.3.4 is shows a *Plesk Web Server's Default Page*.

`a2query -m php5` says *"php5 (enabled by maintainer script)"*

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might not be with the PHP.

Upload a static html file or a picture to /var/www/html and try accessing it through the browser - if it shows then it is probable a PHP problem and if it displays another 404 it might be a problem with the apache config... For example the default site that is enabled might reside in another folder.

Comment: I was hoping in another type of answers, like _"of course it cannot work, because..."_ but, indeed, yours indicates that all should work but it doesn't, it's the worst case.  I uploaded a picture and still got a *Not found* error.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, you were right, thanks again. Checking `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I've found the problem
`'[Fri Jun 05 22:39:40.877182 2015] [:error] [pid 7394] [client <...>] script '/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/info.php' not found or unable to stat'`
How and where is this set as default site ? for sure not in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Comment: Check the other config files in /etc/apache2/ - the default site might be declared there. You can also make a global search in files for the word htdocs (if you don't know how, you can try this link for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux )